# Next js 14 server compoent throwing error 405 mehtod not forund where as there are no api routes in my app works fine in local

Tags: next.js

Next js 14 server compoent throwing error 405 mehtod not forund where as there are no api routes in my app works fine in local

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/on6zs.png)

Is there a way to fix this? Any one can help me resovling this issue?